# Do I need to render the HTML in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to render the `HTML` files server-side on an native mobile app compiled with Phonegap, or do I need feed the app with `JSON` and render the `HTML` in the app (with some js-library)?

Comment: Yes, it possible. $.get('*.html, function(html){//Return content of html file }');

Comment: Though this is possible, consider the fact that if the user is not connected to the internet, the app will be a blank page.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the "standard/normal" way of rendering the HTML in Phonegap is by some js-library like Angular or Ember?